# Postman test to check if every item of response's body has id existing in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, postman

The task is to check if every item of response's body has id existing in an array. Let me show you an example:

```
let json = [
    { "name": "Ford", "id": "6" },
    { "name": "BMW", "id": "7" },
    { "name": "Abcd", "id": "8" },
    { "name": "Def", "id": "9" },
    { "name": "Ford", "id": "12" },
    { "name": "GHI", "id": "10" }
]

let ids = ["6", "7", "8", "9"]
```

I would like to check if every item form json has and id existing in ids. I tried using a loop like this one

```
 for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        console.log(ids.includes(json[i].id))
    }
```

But i guess there must be more appropriate way. How would you write a test for this task?

Comment: there are obviously more ways to do it but if your end goal is to check the ids only then I think you're on the right track

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using forEach instead of for:

```js
pm.test("Every item has id an from ids[]", () => {
    response.forEach(element => pm.expect(element.id).to.be.oneOf(ids));
});
```

Or check if every element has an id to make it more "generic"

```js
pm.test("Every item has an id", () => {
    response.forEach(element => pm.expect(element).to.has.deep.property('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks mkamranhamid, I might have jumped the gun with this post. I've realised that it could be done like this:

```
pm.test("Every item has id from ids[]", function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        pm.expect(json[i].id).to.be.oneOf(ids)
    }
})
```